# Applying Eisenstein's criterion to $x^3 + x^2 − 2x − 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Is it possible to apply a shift (to the variable $x$) and Eisenstein's criterion to show that the polynomial $f(x) = x^3 + x^2 − 2x − 1$ is irreducible over the rationals?

Comment: Isn't it easier to just check for rational roots?

Comment: @Surb thanks. can you explain?

Comment: @lulu yes, I agree but I want to know if I can use Eisenstein (with a shift)

Answer (score 1):

You can shift by 9 to get $x^3 +28x^2+259x+791$ which is irreducible by looking at divisibility by 7.

Comment: $9\equiv\text{something smaller}\bmod 7$.  Why did you not try that smaller shift?  (The smaller shift also gives a square-free constant term.)